# Where to ask questions about ebooks and learning materials?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know that where I would post questions if they were related to ebook suggestions or suggestions related to where I can find training materials. The following question I asked was flagged as off topic and down voted (Note in the comments section it is said that learning material cannot be linked) -:

[Getting stated with windows administration](https://superuser.com/questions/753288/getting-started-with-windows-administration)

So if I wanted to know where to look for Windows Administration materials where would I ask them ?

Comment: Have you looked on Amazon (which has book reviews)? or technical ebook companies (such as [Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com)) that also has reviews?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nowhere in the Stack Exchange network. This network don't cater to that kind of question. Questions asking for links to off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I understand that asking for off-site resources are not allowed but is it okay someone answers a particular question by posting off-site resources ? Like this following question-:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919051/finding-undocumented-apis-in-windows

Comment: Yes, so long as they *supplement* your answer, off-site links are fine.